# Using grpc in maven

Tags: java, maven, grpc

Does anyone know how to compile *.proto files for grpc application in maven?

This is how I'm compiling protobuf in maven - (old way, using installed protoc compiler, excerpt from pom.xml):

```
  <build>
    <plugins>

      <!-- protocol buffers runner, requires protoc -->
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>generate-protobuf-sources</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <configuration>
              <tasks>
                <mkdir dir="target/generated-sources/java" />

                <exec executable="protoc">
                  <arg value="--java_out=target/generated-sources/java" />
                  <arg value="src/main/protobuf/hello.proto" />
                </exec>
              </tasks>
              <sourceRoot>target/generated-sources/java</sourceRoot>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
              <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

I wonder if something similar is possible for grpc. From what I understand I need to somehow connect protoc-gen-grpc-java plugin with protobuf, but I'm not sure how to do that.

UPDATE: For those who interested I created a fully working example of client-server app using maven [on github](https://github.com/avshabanov/examples/tree/master/src/rpc/hello-grpc).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'd highly recommend using `protobuf-maven-plugin` as described in the grpc-java [README](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/README.md).

If you really want to do it manually, you can download protoc-gen-grpc-java from [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22protoc-gen-grpc-java%22) and add another <arg> for the exec of protoc:
`--plugin=protoc-gen-grpc-java=path/to/protoc-gen-grpc-java`

Comment: I updated my question with a link to my github repo with a fully working example.

Comment: Step by step tutorial using grpc-java and maven at https://bertrandszoghy.wordpress.com/2017/06/01/protocol-buffers-grpc-client-and-server-using-secure-channels-with-java/

Answer (score 2):

[protoc-jar-maven-plugin](https://github.com/os72/protoc-jar-maven-plugin) does not require installing the protoc compiler, unlike protobuf-maven-plugin.

Add this to your plugins:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.github.os72</groupId>
    <artifactId>protoc-jar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.11.4</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

and it uses the cross platform protoc-jar to generate your protobuf.